# good, free undelete for windows?

Tags: windows, robocopy, undelete

I was using robocopy and accidentally included the /MIR command which deletes everything on the destination drive which isnt in the source - *face palm*

is findNtfs my best option? Ive had luck with this one before.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Set your expectations low. If anything robocopy then copied was written over the 'deleted' data, you will lose it.

I've never used the software you mention but I have done a small amount of recovery and the best tools I found were often designed towards certain formats. For example 'photorec' was great when I wanted to get tens of thousands of jpegs recovered.

http://www.piriform.com/recuva has also helped me before now.

At the end of the day, if what you lost is important, take the drive offline and stop writing to it. Use every piece of recovery software you can find until you get your data back or it stops being worth it.

If you've had luck with a tool before, try it again seen as you're familiar with it. At the end of the day, they shouldn't be writing to disk and so you can use software until you find one that works.

Comment: I'd give you +2 if I could for not just warning the user but also mentioning PhotoRec too.  [GetDataBack](http://www.runtime.org/) is also a good program, though not free.

Comment: "I'd give you +2 if I could" - I'm not quite sure what you mean so I'm just going to nod my head.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck with [Restoration](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/restoration.HTML). It's small (a single executable) and free.

Comment: The software named Restoration mentioned in another answer is filled with Adware. My antivirus software found 4 different adware software.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime Get Data back is good and has the advantage that it will show what it will be able to recover before you buy.

http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm